# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

This is the constructor for the group class that acts similarly to a set.

```
    constructor(){
        this.list = [];
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](){
        return new GroupIterator(this.list);
    }
```

This should make group objects itterable but I can't find the error.

```
class GroupIterator{

    constructor(group){
        this.group = group;
        this.position = 0;
    }

    next(){
        let result = {
            value: undefined,
            done: true,
        };
        if(this.position >= this.group.list.length){
            return result;
        }
        result.value = group.list[this.position];
        result.done = false;
        this.position++;
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: when you are debugging, what do you receive as a parameter in your constructor

Comment: How about `return new GroupIterator(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a small error here, it should be `this.group.length`, not `this.group.list.length`,  the list IS named group.  For reference:

```
class GroupIterator{
  constructor(group){
    this.group = group
    this.position = 0
  }

  next() {
    let result = {
      value: undefined,
      done: true,
    }

    if(this.position >= this.group.length){
      return result
    }

    result.value = this.group[this.position]
    result.done = false
    this.position++
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: `group[this.position]` should be `this.group[this.position]`

Answer (score 0):

Because your property is called `group` - there's no `list` attached, because `group` is the array you passed to the constructor.

```
if (this.position >= this.group.length) {...}
```

And make sure to replace `group[this.position]` with `this.group[this.position]`.

Comment: Also `this.group[this.position]`

Comment: Ok @Barmar, I'll add that